# Android if I have a lot of the same elements in layout

Tags: android, android-layout

My layout has a lot of elements and I want to divide them using "divider":

```
        <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>
```

But I don't want to add the same divider 10 times in layout. Can I do something to help me to add divider only one time? With button I have the same question. I have 3 button in different places in my layout, but this button doing the same. How can i bind one action for three button and add only one time in layout?

Comment: You can create a Layout for your button an include this layout each time, but for one button, this is probably not the best choice (same for the divider)

Comment: If you have 3 buttons, you need to add it three times to the layout. The onClick can stay the same

Comment: onClick method doesn't work in fragment!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of Items that use the same layout, ie. they look a lot like each other, ListView with an ArrayAdapter is very, very useful.

Comment: This method is good, but one item of listView must contain all the elements (button, textview, edittext etc). It's bad for design some items you must show, some you need to hide.

Comment: Actually, that is quite easy. If you create your own, you can pass it an Array of objects that set what you want to show or not. setVisibility(INVISIBLE / VISIBLE / GONE); Using a recycle view it works nicely in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can done this type of job by creating custom button. Custom button extends the Button class. Something like this e.g:

```
public class MyButton extends Button {

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_button_layout, this, true);

    }

    public MyButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }


}
```

Comment: For 3 buttons this method have a lot of code because you must create all infrastructure for button (pressed, focused, disabled layout etc)

Comment: This is not lot of code because if you have a look your 3 button code together it must more code with compare that code